# Encrypt db file to crypt12 format

Tags: encryption, whatsapp, bcrypt, encryption-symmetric

I have decrypted `crypt12` file into `.db` file. Modified some changes. Now again, Is there a way to encrypt `.db` file into `crypt12` format?